# "Unknown directive model" when setting up AWS Amplify GraphQL API in WebStorm

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, graphql, webstorm, aws-amplify

I'm using the following AWS Amplify tutorial for Angular:

https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/data-model/q/integration/angular#model-the-data-with-graphql-transform

When I generate the GraphQL API I get red warning messages for the `@model` directive:

[image]

I'm using WebStorm. How can I get my editor to not throw these red warning errors? Do I need to install some @types package or install some plugin?

Comment: ... ask support?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, create `.graphqlconfig` file with the following content:

```
{
  "schemaPath": "schema.graphql",
  "includes": ["*"],
  "extensions": {
    "endpoints": {}
  }
}
```

Then, create `graphql-directives.js` file with the following content:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

const clientSchemaExtensions = gql`
  directive @model on OBJECT
  scalar AWSDateTime
`;
```

After that, there are no syntax errors anymore!

[image]

This answer was adapted [from this repo](https://github.com/jimkyndemeyer/graphql-config-examples/tree/master/extend-client-fields-and-directives).

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly!
I created graphql-directives.js under amplify directory. I made this definition file to cover all (most?) of directives and types for Amplify here; https://gist.github.com/pikanji/dcb6749293ddb4c68332c56ee910d1ba

Answer (score 2):

#### Amplify Repository Updates

It looks like all the Amplify transformer directives were published at this `@aws-amplify` repo subdirectory two weeks ago:

- https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-category-api/tree/main/packages

You can dig into the source files to find the exact definitions. For example if you dig down to this file:

- https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-category-api/blob/main/packages/amplify-graphql-default-value-transformer/src/graphql-default-value-transformer.ts

You will find:

```
const directiveDefinition = `
  directive @${directiveName}(value: String!) on FIELD_DEFINITION
`;
```

You can also take a look at this NPM page that lists all the individual directive packages that depend on **[@aws-amplify/.graphql-transformer-core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-amplify/graphql-transformer-core)**

#### Default Transformer

The **[Default Transformer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-amplify/graphql-default-value-transformer)** page includes this helpful information:

- [Default Transformer Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJWUW.png)